# Angular 2 CustomReuseStrategy to preserve the searches lost on page refresh

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

I was playing with CustomReuseStrategy that implements the RouteReuseStrategy

It looks like the routes that we store to reuse are lost when we refresh the page.
Is there any way to preserve the routes even on page refresh? I would like them to remain saved to be reused until I actually logout from the app.

Comment: The routes are persisted in the url. If you do a reload, there is no way for Angular to restore more from that. You can persist yourself in localstorage or on the server.

Comment: Gunter, so if I want to persist on page refresh too, CustomReuseStrategy is not the right way to go then? Do I have to persist each single data I want save in localstorage or server?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "each single data". You need to persist, what you want to recover after reload. `CustomReuseStrategy` is only to retain component instances when you navigate between different components.